Align an object to Camera View with Geometry Nodes without instance on points
Here is a Geo-node tree- It doesn't work as well as "Add Object Constraint" in terms of keeping the position of all the objects in my scene.
I will show pictures of both below.


Is there  a way to build an object that always faces the camera in geometry nodes without the Instance on points node?
I have a suspicion it is offsetting objects referenced in my node tree  instead of just rotating them.  If you instance two or more objects, does it create a new pivot point?  It works perfectly if I use the constraint, but I was hoping for  a GN solution.

Replace "Points" and "Instance on Points" nodes with "Transform Geometry" node.

Creating "Text Cloud" like in comics

Thanks, @MarkusvonBroady, I'll check out that post.  You intuited more or less what this was about.  It is callouts not speech bubbles, in this case, but same difference.    I'll check your suggestion out and see if it works for me.

Here was the solution to my specific problem.
I had an object info node, calling an empty, that was being offset when I instanced my whole geometry node tree.  I discovered that what I needed was for the empty to control the center position, and the camera to control the rotation, and for both object nodes to be set to "relative".
This solution replaced the group above:

